# Sending value to another activity and save them into listview

Tags: android, android-activity

I have in my MapsActivity several markers, every time I click in one of them a alertdialog shows up, this alertdialog contains some information regarding that marker and three buttons (Cancel, Like, Go) when I click on the "Like" button I want to send to another activity (Favoritos) the values from that marker.
The marker values are retrieved from json like this:

> final int position = (int) marker.getTag();

How can I send "position" to my other activity without making a intent

Here's java:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            final int position = (int) marker.getTag();
            final String latRepr = listaOportunidades.get(position).get("Coord_LAT");
            final String lngRepr = listaOportunidades.get(position).get("Coord_LONG");

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(listaOportunidades.get(position).get("Designacao"))
                    .setMessage("  • Endereço: " + listaOportunidades.get(position).get("Morada") + "\n" + "  • Telefone: " + listaOportunidades.get(position).get("Telefone")
                            + "\n" + "  • Telemóvel: " + listaOportunidades.get(position).get("Telemovel") + "\n" + "  • Email: " + listaOportunidades.get(position).get("Email"))
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.iconmarker)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            new GetDirecoes().execute(latRepr, lngRepr);
                            mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(250);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNeutralButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Like", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            int position = (int) marker.getTag();

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guardado nos favoritos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface between your activities. In your MapsActivity, create an interface:

```
public interface OnMarkerSelected() {
 void onSelected(int position);
}
```

declare field:

```
OnMarkerSelected listener;
```

in your Dialog Like Click do something like:

```
if (listener != null) {
  listener.onSelected(position);
}
```

Then go to your other activity and `implement` your interface `OnMarkerSelected.`

You will then have to implement method `onSelected(int position)`, where you will have access to that position.

This is not a full solution and probably some things are missing, but it should give you the right idea and put you on correct path to solve your problem.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the favorite marker using preferences or some database like SQLite or Realm, but I recommend using preferences in this case. There's an example of what you can implement:

To access to your preferences you have to always call the same strings, so, to prevent bad practiques create the Strings resources that you'll need:

```
<string name="MyPreferencesString">preferencesOfMyApp</string>
<string name="MyPreferencesMarkers">favoriteMarkers</string>
```

Declare a global SharedPreferences variable:

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
```

Initiate the preferences in the `onCrete` method:

```
preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.MyPreferencesString), MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To add or modify preferences (in this case we are only saving an int, but you can put more value types):

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.MyPreferencesMarkers),position); 
editor.commit(); //or editor.apply();
```

To get a value from your preferences:

```
int anotherPositionVariable = preferences.getInt(getString(R.string.MyPreferencesMarkers),0);
```

Tip: Refresh the object of preference before accessing any value by calling it the same way it was initialized.

Documentation about the preferences:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html